# How to enter a new view from a UITableViewCell? (when the table view gets its information from a .plist)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, view, tableview

I want to make a new view appear when i press a table view cell. But i seem to have som problems because my table view cells gets thei information from a .plist file i made. Here is my code. PS: I am making this in Storyboard.

ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (copy, nonatomic) NSDictionary *firstTableView;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSArray *firstTableViewKey;


@end
```

ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"


static NSString *SectionsTableIdentifier = @"SectionsTableIdentifier";

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITableView *tableView = (id)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
    [tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:SectionsTableIdentifier];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"firstTableView" ofType:@"plist"];

    self.firstTableView = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];

    self.firstTableViewKey = [[self.firstTableView allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

    tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    tableView.opaque = NO;
    tableView.backgroundView = nil;

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table View Data Source Methods
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return [self.firstTableViewKey count];

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    NSString *key = self.firstTableViewKey[section];
    NSArray *nameSection = self.firstTableView[key];
    return [nameSection count];

}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return self.firstTableViewKey[section];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SectionsTableIdentifier];

    NSString *key = self.firstTableViewKey[indexPath.section];
    NSArray *nameSection = self.firstTableView[key];

    cell.textLabel.text = nameSection[indexPath.row];
    return cell;

}

@end
```

Thanks for any kind of help!

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: The problem is that i want to open a new view when i press a tableviewcell

Comment: And i don't know how to do that when i have gotten my tableview's information from å plist file.

Comment: Are you using storyboards?

Comment: Did the solution I posted work for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to push the view Modally with storyboards you could use:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard       = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
NewViewController *VC   = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"A_STRING_ID FOR_YOUR_VC_IN_STORYBOARDS"];
    [self presentViewController:VC animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Where the string (A_STRING_ID FOR_YOUR_VC_IN_STORYBOARDS) can be populated from your plist file, or wherever you get the text

If you want to move it via a navigation stack with Storyboards

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle: nil]; 
NewViewController *VC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"A_STRING_ID FOR_YOUR_VC_IN_STORYBOARDS"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:VC animated:YES];
```